# Database Query not working

Tags: functions, database, sql

I've been following a tutorial by Steve Marks which goes throught adding information from posts to a new `Database Table` as well as the usual `postmeta` one. However no matter what I try, It will not store the information in the new table, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Tutorial is available here: http://biostall.com/performing-a-radial-search-with-wp_query-in-wordpress 
my post type is `festival-event` and i made the names of my custom post types the same as in the function to see if I was missing something there.

The `SQL` I used to creat the table in the db was:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lat_lng_post` (  
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `lat` float NOT NULL,  
  `lng` float NOT NULL  
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And the function in my `functions.php` file is:

```
function save_lat_lng( $post_id )   
{  
    global $wpdb;  

    // Check that we are editing the right post type  
    if ( 'location' != $_POST['festival-event'] )   
    {  
        return;  
    }  

    // Check if we have a lat/lng stored for this property already  
    $check_link = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM lat_lng_post WHERE post_id = '" . $post_id . "'");  
    if ($check_link != null)   
    {  
        // We already have a lat lng for this post. Update row  
        $wpdb->update(   
        'lat_lng_post',   
        array(   
            "lat" => $_POST['lat_field_name'],  
            "lng" => $_POST['lng_field_name']  
        ),   
        array( "post_id" => $post_id ),   
        array(   
            "%f",  
            "%f"  
        )  
        );  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        // We do not already have a lat lng for this post. Insert row  
        $wpdb->insert(   
        "lat_lng_post",   
        array(   
            "post_id" => $post_id,  
            "lat" => $_POST['lat_field_name'],  
            "lng" => $_POST['lng_field_name']  
        ),   
        array(   
            "%d",   
            "%f",  
            "%f"  
        )   
        );  
    }  

}  
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_lat_lng' );
```

I've been researching load on what the problem could be but no luck whatsoever, I'm really stuck. Attached is images of PHPMyAdmin so you can see the db [image: screenshot of phpMyAdmin]

Comment: var_dump( $check_link );  Is it what you expect?

Comment: First, this line `if ( 'location' != $_POST['festival-event'] ) ` should be `if ( 'festival-event' != $_POST['post_type'] )`

Comment: @czerspalace That worked,how stupid of me, do you want to write it as answer and i'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line

```
    if ( 'location' != $_POST['festival-event'] )
```

should be

```
    if ( 'festival-event' != $_POST['post_type'] )
```